# What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor, c++-faq, ctor-initializer

Recently I've seen an example like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
  int bar;
  Foo(int num): bar(num) {};
};

int main(void) {
  std::cout << Foo(42).bar << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

What does this strange `: bar(num)` mean? It somehow seems to initialize the data member, but I've never seen this syntax before. It looks like a function/constructor call but for an `int`. This makes no sense to me.

Are there any other esoteric language features like this, you'll never find in an ordinary C++ book?

Comment: An "ordinary c++ book" that doesn't mention this is probably a c book where someone thought "++" would look cool on the cover ...

Comment: "you'll never find in a ordinary C++ book". Oh. Dear. Throw away your "ordinary C++ book" right now. Not out the window - somebody else might pick it up. Preferably shred it and put it for recycling. Done? Now consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list to get a new book.

Comment: This language feature is hardly esoteric.  It's a fairly major feature of object construction.

Comment: In fact, far from esoteric, you often have no choice but to use initializer lists. For example, if your class contains a `const` member variable, or a reference, you have to use an initalizer list.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

It's a *member initialization list*.  You should find information about it in any [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

[You should, in most cases, initialize all member objects in the member initialization list](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#init-lists) (however, do note the exceptions listed at the end of the FAQ entry).

The takeaway point from the FAQ entry is that,

> All other things being equal, your code will run faster if you use initialization lists rather than assignment.

Comment: Knowing the terminology is critical - I'm jealous that I didn't think of it.

Comment: There are also a bunch of other reasons for using init lists. especially when the order of initialisation matters. 
It's a shame it has such a stupid fake function call syntax.

Comment: You should *always* initialize member variables, unless it's *really* okay for them to contain garbage after their parent object is instantiated (e.g., I/O buffers). Because you're guaranteed to get garbage in them if you don't.

Comment: @mgb, the initialization list does not determine the order of initialization. Member variables are initialized in the order they are declared in the class, even if that differs from the order of the initializations on the constructor.

Comment: @mgb: I don't think it's intended as a fake function call syntax. It's initialization syntax, like `int i(23);`, `std::vector<double> emptyVec(0);`, `std::vector<double> fullVec(10,23.);`, etc. Only with the type removed, of course, because the type is in the member declaration.

Comment: @Martin : It doesn't have a function call syntax, it has a construction syntax (ala: new String("Name")). It fits in with the constructor better than Foo(int num) : m_Count = 5. Not to mention that classes must be constructed at this point anyway, since it's initialized here. Foo(int num) : Bar = num, wouldn't compile right. It just seems weird seeing Foo(int num) : m_Count(num), since primitive types aren't constructed.

Comment: @Steve, in the init list it almost makes sense - but I don't like the fashion for using it in code. `int name(10)` isn't as clear as `int name=10;` as far as i'm concerned

Comment: Prefer "member initialisation list" or `ctor-initializer`, please. "Initialization list" is ambiguous and confusing when you consider `{1,2,3,4,5}`.

Answer (score 421):

```
Foo(int num): bar(num)
```

This construct is called a **Member Initializer List** in C++.

Simply said, it **initializes** your member `bar` to a value `num`.

---

### What is the difference between Initializing and Assignment inside a constructor?

**Member Initialization:**

```
Foo(int num): bar(num) {};
```

**Member Assignment:**

```
Foo(int num)
{
   bar = num;
}
```

There is a significant difference between Initializing a member using Member initializer list and assigning it an value inside the constructor body.

When you ***initialize*** fields via Member initializer list the constructors will be called once and the object will be constructed and initialized in one operation.

If you use ***assignment*** then the fields will be first initialized with default constructors and then reassigned (via assignment operator) with actual values.

As you see there is an additional overhead of creation & assignment in the latter, which might be considerable for user defined classes.

```
Cost of Member Initialization = Object Construction 
Cost of Member Assignment = Object Construction + Assignment
```

The latter is actually equivalent to:

```
Foo(int num) : bar() {bar = num;}
```

While the former is equivalent to just:

```
Foo(int num): bar(num){}
```

For an inbuilt (your code example) or POD class members there is no practical overhead.

---

### When do you HAVE TO use Member Initializer list?

You will **have(rather forced) to** use a Member Initializer list if:

- Your class has a reference member
- Your class has a non static const member or
- Your class member doesn't have a default constructor or
- For initialization of base class members or
- When constructor’s parameter name is same as data member(this is not really a MUST)

---

### A code example:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
  // Reference member, has to be Initialized in Member Initializer List
  int &i;
  int b;
  // Non static const member, must be Initialized in Member Initializer List
  const int k;

  // Constructor’s parameter name b is same as class data member
  // Other way is to use this->b to refer to data member
  MyClass(int a, int b, int c) : i(a), b(b), k(c) {
    // Without Member Initializer
    // this->b = b;
  }
};

class MyClass2 : public MyClass {
public:
  int p;
  int q;
  MyClass2(int x, int y, int z, int l, int m) : MyClass(x, y, z), p(l), q(m) {}
};

int main() {
  int x = 10;
  int y = 20;
  int z = 30;
  MyClass obj(x, y, z);

  int l = 40;
  int m = 50;
  MyClass2 obj2(x, y, z, l, m);

  return 0;
}
```

- `MyClass2` doesn't have a default constructor so it has to be initialized through member initializer list.
- Base class `MyClass` does not have a default constructor, So to initialize its member one will need to use Member Initializer List.

---

### Important points to Note while using Member Initializer Lists:

**Class Member variables are always initialized in the order in which they are declared in the class.**

They are **not** initialized in the order in which they are specified in the Member Initializer List.
In short, Member initialization list does not determine the order of initialization.

Given the above it is always a good practice to maintain the same order of members for Member initialization as the order in which they are declared in the class definition. This is because compilers do not warn if the two orders are different but a relatively new user might confuse member Initializer list as the order of initialization and write some code dependent on that.

Comment: @nils This is the best answer so far. The order of the initialization Als pointed out is also extremely important, while the Visual Studio compiler won't say anything about that, other compiler like gcc will fail. It is also important to note depending your compiler and the situation it is **not Always true** that this will improve performance or be more efficient.

Comment: If I have a constructor with a lot of variables says more than 10, will that be inconvenient to list all of them in that list order?

Comment: @ryf9059: Why do you think it will be inconvenient? You have to list them anyways, so why not in order same as that of declaration.

Comment: You may want to clarify some of your terminology, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31275680/1708801) was asked in order to clarify some of the details in your answer. The details are somewhat orthogonal to the original question asked here.

Comment: this should have been the answer. thank god i scrolled down else i would have missed it.

Comment: @ryf9059 Your point makes sense to me considering length of one line. I guess the initialization can be broken into multiple lines in case the list is lengthly so that inconvenience you are probably mentioning can be avoided.

Comment: @AlokSave You said MyClass2 and MyClass doesn't have a default constructor. Default constructor you mean user defined no argument constructor?

Comment: @AlokSave __MyClass(int a, int b, int c) : i(a), b(b), k(c) {__
    // Without Member Initializer
    // this->b = b;
  __}__  it should be like this __MyClass(int `&a` , int b, int c) : i(a), b(b), k(c) {__
    // Without Member Initializer
    // this->b = b;
  __}__  and so respective changes in declaration and call. without this change `i` will refer to `a` but `a` can't refer to `x` as it contain just value of `x` so indirectly `i` can't refer to   `x`. so if we modify value of `i` then it just modify `a` but not `x`

Comment: @AbhishekMane You are right, and here is a link to the related question showing it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67619383/3150802

Answer (score 18):

That's constructor initialisation.  It is the correct way to initialise members in a class constructor, as it prevents the default constructor being invoked.

Consider these two examples:

```
// Example 1
Foo(Bar b)
{
   bar = b;
}

// Example 2
Foo(Bar b)
   : bar(b)
{
}
```

In example 1:

```
Bar bar;  // default constructor
bar = b;  // assignment
```

In example 2:

```
Bar bar(b) // copy constructor
```

It's all about efficiency.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is about efficiency. It is about providing a way to initialize something that requires initialization, but cannot be default-initualized. For some reason people mention constants and references as the examples, while the most obvious example would be classes without default constructors.

Comment: We're both right; in his example you could argue for efficiency; for the const/reference/no default constructor issue it's both efficiency and necessity.  I upvoted an answer below because of it :)

[Farnsworth voice] It can do other things. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: `Bar bar();  // default constructor` Are you sure?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Just curious to know : What should that be according to you?

Answer (score 16):

This is called an initialization list.  It is a way of initializing class members.  There are benefits to using this instead of simply assigning new values to the members in the body of the constructor, but if you have class members which are *constants* or *references* they *must* be initialized.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Point taken, but the constants or references point is still valid in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

This is not obscure, it's the [C++ initialization list syntax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Basically, in your case, `x` will be initialized with `_x`, `y` with `_y`, `z` with `_z`.

Answer (score 8):

The other already explained to you that the syntax that you observe is called "constructor initializer list". This syntax lets you to custom-initialize base subobjects and member subobjects of the class (as opposed to allowing them to default-initialize or to remain uninitialized).

I just want to note that the syntax that, as you said, "looks like a constructor call", is not necessarily a constructor call. In C++ language the `()` syntax is just one standard form of *initialization syntax*. It is interpreted differently for different types. For class types with user-defined constructor it means one thing (it is indeed a constructor call), for class types without user-defined constructor it means another thing (so called [***value initialization***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) ) for empty `()`) and for non-class types it again means something different (since non-class types have no constructors).

In your case the data member has type `int`. `int` is not a class type, so it has no constructor. For type `int` this syntax means simply "initialize `bar` with the value of `num`" and that's it. It is done just like that, directly, no constructors involved, since, once again, `int` is not a class type of therefore it can't have any constructors.

Comment: But bjarne stroustrup in his book TC++PL & The C++ Programming language  says that _"Built-in types also have default constructors"_ . http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-default-constructor-built-in-types/ & http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=15 also says _built in types have constructors_. I personally asked this question to bjarne via mail & he says me that yes, built in types also have constructors. so your answer is wrong !!!

Comment: @Destructor: My answer is absolutely correct. Bjarne Stroustrup deliberately and explicitly **lied** in his book for the sake of simplifying it. Compare the size of the TC++PL book and the size of C++ language standard. See the difference? The price to pay for relative compactness of TC++PL is such obvious (and well-known to everyone) errors and omissions as the one you mentioned (there are quite a few others as well). So, to put it more succinctly: my answer is right, TC++PL is wrong. But for a person like you, who is just beginning to learn, TC++PL is good enough.

Comment: And please don't tell us trollish fairy tales about "asked this question to bjarne via mail". This issue is, again, well-known and has been exhaustively discussed and closed a long time ago. (But even if he said something like that to you, it wouldn't matter anyway.) In the end, the only thing that matters is what the language specification says. What Bjarne Stroustrup says is irrelevant. The post on geeksforgeeks you linked is completely bogus.

Comment: So, you think that standard is bug free? C++ standard has also bugs.

Comment: @Destructor: Of course, it does. However, the standard *defines* the language. Everything the standard says is The Absolute Truth by definition. The only "bugs" it can possibly have are mostly wording-related things like self-contradictory wording, ambiguous wording, under-specified and so forth. Such bugs are vehemently sought out, reported, documented, discussed and resolved. "Bugs" in the intent can also exist, but they are a matter of debate.

Comment: The concept of "initialization" and the role of "constructors" has been around for a long time. The intent is clear and the corresponding wording is clear as well. There are no bugs there. And even if there are bugs in the wording, the intent is, again, perfectly clear. The intent is not being debated. You want to challenge this intent - you can submit a proposal to the committee. But at this moment in C++ only class types can have constructors.

Comment: Ok, thank you sir for taking your time for this wonderful in depth explanation !!!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how you could miss this one, it's pretty basic. That's the syntax for initializing member variables or base class constructors.  It works for plain old data types as well as class objects.

Comment: Written on one line inside the declaration like that it's easy to not spot it as an init list

Answer (score 6):

This is an initialization list. It'll initialize the members before the constructor body is run.
Consider

```
class Foo {
 public:
   string str;
   Foo(string &p)
   {
      str = p;
   };
 };
```

vs

```
class Foo {
public:
  string str;
  Foo(string &p): str(p) {};
};
```

In the first example, str will be initialized by its no-argument constructor

```
string();
```

before the body of the Foo constructor. Inside the foo constructor, the

```
string& operator=( const string& s );
```

will be called on 'str' as you do   str = p;

Wheras in the second example, str will be initialized directly by
calling its constructor

```
string( const string& s );
```

with 'p' as an argument.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, this is indeed a way to initialize member variables.  I'm not sure that there's much benefit to this, other than clearly expressing that it's an initialization.  Having a "bar=num" inside the code could get moved around, deleted, or misinterpreted much more easily.

Comment: The benefit is that it's usually more efficient.  And, in some cases, such as when you have `const` member variables, or member variables that are references, you *have* to use an initializer list.

Answer (score 5):

there is another 'benefit'

if the member variable type does not support null initialization or if its a reference (which cannot be null initialized) then you have no choice but to supply an initialization list

Answer (score 5):

It's an initialization list for the constructor. Instead of default constructing `x`, `y` and `z` and then assigning them the values received in the parameters, those members will be initialized with those values right off the bat. This may not seem terribly useful for `float`s, but it can be quite a timesaver with custom classes that are expensive to construct.

Answer (score 3):

Not mentioned yet on this thread: since C++11, the member initializer list can use list-initialization  (aka. "uniform initialization", "braced initialization"):

```
Foo(int num): bar{num} {}
```

which has the same semantics as list-initialization in other contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old discussion, I couldn't find any mention about [delegating constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), which uses the weird ":" symbol in the following way.

```
class Foo 
{
public: 
    Foo(char x, int y) 
    {}
    Foo(int y) : Foo('a', y) 
    {}
};
```

What it does is simply delegating `Foo(y)` into `Foo('a', y)` . So that

```
Foo foo(15); //=> foo('a', 15)
```

When defining a delegating constructor, you cannot have any members in initializer list besides targeted constructor.

Answer (score 1):

### What is the colon syntax (`:`) in the class constructor and what does passing an integer to a `std::vector<>` constructor do?

I'd like to explain the below example from [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73563851/4561887):

```cpp
class UnionFind {
    public:
        UnionFind(int sz) : root(sz) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
                root[i] = i;
            }
        }
    private:
        vector<int> root;
    };
    
    
    int main() {
        
       
        UnionFind uf(10);
    }
```

The colon (`:`) signifies the start of an "initialization list", or ["initializer list"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), which initializes each variable to the value in parenthesis. It is as though you were calling a constructor for each variable with that value in parenthesis being passed in to that variable's constructor.

So, `: root(sz)` initializes the `root` variable with an `int sz`, which is like doing `vector<int> root(sz);`. Doing it like this, however, allows `sz` to get passed in to the `UnionFind` class constructor.

Initializing a vector with a size like that is constructor #3 here (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```cpp
// Constructor (3) as shown at
// https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector
explicit vector( size_type count,
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

It constructs `count` (`sz` in the example above) number of elements into the vector, each with value `T()`, which means `int()` in this case since `root` is a `vector<int>`. `int()` looks like a function call but is basically an integer default constructor to value zero (`0`). It is called ["value initialization"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Think of it like calling an "integer constructor", if integers were objects and had constructors. See also my question here: [What is a call to `char()` as a function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72367123/4561887)

So, let's recap: `: root(sz)` in the constructor is like constructing `vector<int> root(sz);`, which creates `sz` number of elements in the `root` vector, each with initial value `int()`, which is the syntax for ["value initialization"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of an `int` to zero.

Note also that the `count` parameter passed to constructor #3 shown above really should be a `size_type`, which can be written as `std::vector::size_type`, and is usually `size_t` (see the "Member types" section [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)). So, it would be better to change `int sz` to `size_t sz` instead. Therefore, change this constructor line: `UnionFind(int sz) : root(sz) {` to this instead: `UnionFind(size_t sz) : root(sz) {`.